# how to make a change for only one item in a rendered react list?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i have a list of divs and buttons associated with them. when i click on any one of the divs,
i want only ONE button, which is associated with that div to be displayed.
however with the code i've written all the buttons are displayed upon clicking any one div.

i've set a state which prevents displaying of any button in the initial state, and when a div is clicked, i set the state to true, which lets the button element be displayed.

but this method causes all buttons to be shown. how do i fix this?

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';

export function App(props) {

  let [startconv,setStartconv]=useState(false);
  let current=[{name:'yaba1',age:20},{name:'yaba2',age:23}]

  let handleclicker=(o)=>{
    setStartconv(true);
    console.log(o);
  }


  return (
    <div className="online">
      
      {current.map((o) => (
        <div key={o.age}>
          <div className="allonline" style={{ border: 'blue 2px solid', marginBottom: '15px', width: '300px' }} onClick={() => handleclicker(o)}>
            <div className="onlinepfpcont">
              <img alt=" " />
            </div>
            <span className="onlineusername" style={{ color: 'red' }}>{o.name}</span>
          </div>
          {startconv && <button className="startconvobutton" >start {o.name}</button>}
        </div>

      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below to display one button at a time

1. keep the state initially empty
2. add index to the map function
3. pass the index to the hand click function
4. set the index to the state from `handleclicker` function
5. compare the index with the state

I'm hoping it works.

```
 //keep the state initially empty
let [startconv,setStartconv]=useState();
let current=[{name:'yaba1',age:20},{name:'yaba2',age:23}]

let handleclicker=(i)=>{
 // set the index to the state
  setStartconv(i);
}


return (
<div className="online">
 //add index here 
  {current.map((o, i) => (
    <div key={o.age}>
     // pass index to the hand click function
      <div ....... onClick={() => handleclicker(i)}> 
        .........rest of the code ........
      </div>
     // compare the index with the state
      {startconv === i && <button className="startconvobutton" >start {o.name}</button>}
    </div>

  ))}
</div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create an empty object called `startConvStates` with unique
  identifiers as keys and set their initial values to `false`.
- When a div is clicked, update `startConvStates` by changing the value
  from `false` to `true` for the corresponding key.
- While rendering the buttons, check `startConvStates` for the
  corresponding key, and only display the button if its value is
  `true`.

please change the `handleclicker` function below

```
let handleclicker = (o) => {
    setStartConvStates((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [o.age]: true }));
    console.log(o);
  };
```

complate code below

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  let [startConvStates, setStartConvStates] = useState({});

  let current = [
    { name: 'yaba1', age: 20 },
    { name: 'yaba2', age: 23 }
  ];

  let handleclicker = (o) => {
    setStartConvStates((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [o.age]: true }));
    console.log(o);
  };

  return (
    <div className="online">
      {current.map((o) => (
        <div key={o.age}>
          <div
            className="allonline"
            style={{ border: 'blue 2px solid', marginBottom: '15px', width: '300px' }}
            onClick={() => handleclicker(o)}
          >
            <div className="onlinepfpcont">
              <img alt=" " />
            </div>
            <span className="onlineusername" style={{ color: 'red' }}>
              {o.name}
            </span>
          </div>
          {startConvStates[o.age] && <button className="startconvobutton">start {o.name}</button>}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```